# Как правильно организовать работу большого количества потоков (Qthread) c интерфейсом?

Tags: python, qt, gui, qthread

Есть большое кол-во Qthread 1000+ которые посредствам pyqtSignal передают данные в gui поток и обновляют таблицу (QTableWidget). До ~600 потоков проблем нет, но свыше 600 интерфейс начинает, дико тормозить, хотя сами потоки работают в штатном режиме, и выполняют требуемые действия. Как реализовать это, без лагов интерфейса?
Из потока:

```
    self.my_signal_tab_info.emit(list)
```

Обработка:

```
    tab_info.setItem(int(list[0]), int(list[1]), QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(list[2])))
```

в list соответственно [row, col, text]

Минимальный пример

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
import json
import asyncio

with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
    accounts = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if len(line) > 10:
            accounts.append(line.strip())

class main_thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, username, api_id, api_hash, device_model, row, session_string, my_signal_tab_info):
        super().__init__()
        self.username = username
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.device_model = device_model
        self.row = row
        self.session_string = session_string
        self.my_signal_tab_info = my_signal_tab_info

    def set_table_text(self, list):
        self.my_signal_tab_info.emit(list)

    def run(self):
        colinfo = 7
        app_version = '13.12.2'
        system_version = 'SDK 19'
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        client = TelegramClient(StringSession(self.session_string), self.api_id, self.api_hash, use_ipv6=False,
                                proxy=self.proxy,
                                device_model=self.device_model,
                                system_version=system_version,
                                app_version=app_version,
                                lang_code='en',
                                loop=loop)
        self.set_table_text([self.row, colinfo, f'Создали клиент'])
        try:
            client.connect()
            self.set_table_text([self.row, colinfo, f'Подключились к ТГ'])
        except Exception as e:
           self.set_table_text([self.row, colinfo, f'*[Error]Не удалось установить коннект! {e}.'])
        while True:
            self.set_table_text([self.row, colinfo, f'Работаем.'])
            QThread.sleep(5)

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    my_signal_tab_info = pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_signal_tab_info_farm.connect(self.got_info_farm, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.start()

    def got_info_farm(self, tList):
        self.tab_info.setItem(int(tList[0]), int(tList[1]), QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(tList[2])))

    def start(self):
        row = 0
        for acc in accounts:
            row += 1
            acc_data = json.loads(acc)
            username= acc_data['username']
            device_model = acc_data['device']
            acc_api_id = acc_data['api_id']
            acc_api_hash = acc_data['api_hash']
            session_string = acc_data['session_string']
            thread = main_thread(username=username, api_id=acc_api_id, api_hash=acc_api_hash, device_model=device_model,
                                 row=row, session_string=session_string, my_signal_tab_info= self.my_signal_tab_info)
            thread.start()
```

Comment: а Вам точно нужно 1000+ потоков? Но похоже, что просто главный поток не справляется с таким наплывом информации. Может стоит поручить одному потоку задачу двух-трех?

Comment: Да, около 1к потоков нужно точно. Я так же предположил, что просто не справляется, снизил количество передаваемой информации от потока к главному, но результат сильно лучше не стал. И объединить их не получится(

Comment: а чем они таким занимаются? маловероятно, что у Вас количество процессоров хотя бы превышает 32-64, такие потоки не будут эффективно работать.

Comment: По сути в каждом потоке создается клиент телеграма, с использованием, telethone

Comment: ага. а теперь посмотрите на это с другой стороны. Есть у Вас этот список, но смотрите ли Вы все 1000 клиентов одновременно? скорее всего нет, Вы смотрите 20-30, ну максимум 100, если это самсунговский монитор длиной в метр стоит вертикально. А значит, что обновлять все ячейки таблицы не нужно. И для этого есть виртуальный режим. Суть в том, что обновляться будет массив структур в памяти, а таблица/лист будут только запрашивать данные время от времени. И все будет красиво.

Comment: Спасибо, правильная мысль, не думал об этом. Осталось понять как это сделать, если есть информация по этому вопросу, буду очень признателен.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Не надо никаких дополнительных модулей, просто в дополнительном потоке как-то рандомно сформировать похожие данные, которыми вы обновляете таблицу.

Comment: Добавил, вроде этого кода должно быть достаточно.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, актуален еще вопрос или нет, но это очень похоже на то, с чем столкнулся я. Правда используя *Qt С++*.

Всего одна фраза - "Шторм событий". Это то, что устраиваете вы своими **`100500+`** потоками. GUI может не успевать в динамике отрабатывать все.

Попробуйте обновлять не на каждый чих а хотя бы **`1 раз из 100`** и уменьшите количество потоков. 
Ну например - у меня **`1 поток`**, загружает порядка **`50 тысяч`** записей с данными, если на каждую загруженную запись давать сигнал на перерисовку - никакие мультипотоки не помогут. GUI уходит в заморозку.

Передаю сигналы через **`n/100 блоками n/100 записей`**,

- где **`n`** - количество записей подлежащих загрузке.

И все нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Накидаем варианты:

1.Костыли "по быстрому":
Самое узкое место - перерисовка виджета. Можно отключить автоматическое обновление и делать его к примеру по таймеру раз в секунду

```
tab_info.setUpdatesEnabled(False) # отключив апдейты, виджет будет игнорировать автоматически вызываемые при обновлении paint() и update()
massive_Items_Update()
tab_info.setUpdatesEnabled(True) # после завершения работы потоков обновление лучше включить
```

2.Избавиться от QTableWidget и использовать QTableView, реализовав свою модель данных. Обновлять при этом надо будет не сам виджет, а соответствующую модель данных, что существенно быстрее. Помимо бОльшей гибкости и удобства Model-Based виджеты делают репаинт только видимых данных и перерисовывают только их

Comment: Спасибо за идеи, сейчас попробую реализовать 1, возможно этого решения будет достаточно.

Comment: Первый вариант мне не понравился, переделал под 2, запустил в тестирование, спасибо за советы.

Comment: Пока, правда, сделал на стандартной модели, на ней перерисовка так же происходит только видимых данных?

Comment: не видя кода сложно сказать. Можете провести эксперимент, перегрузить data (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) и посмотреть в нем какие элементы перерисовывются